# Domains that satisfy Campanato's Theorem

Tags: analysis, reference-request

A Campanato characterization Hölder continuity holds in domains $\Omega$ such that for all $x_0 \in \Omega$ and $0<r< \mbox{diam}(\Omega)$ we have
 \begin{equation}
 | \Omega \cap B_r(x_0) | \ge A
 \end{equation}
for some $A>0.$ I'd like to know how to interpret such domains. For instance, geometrically. How can I think about a set with such a property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the set is bounded and the boundary is regular the condition is satisfied. However if the domain does have cusp-like spikes in its boundary, as in this picture, the condition is not satisfied.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. English isn't my language, then i have dificulties in undertand such particular terms. Can you give me examples or references in ordem to undertand.

Comment: I added a picture

Comment: Thank you very much for your atention and effort.